# invalid timespan for time string in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm trying to add a string that represents a time to a c# datetime object but I'm getting a exception that says 'invalid format'

```
details.UTCEventDate.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(details.UTCEventTime));
```

where 'details.UTCEventTime' is something like "4:45AM"

Comment: Could you double check that `details.UTCEventTime` is of type `String`?

Answer (score 1):

`AM` and `PM` values are not easily parsed with `TimeSpan.Parse` becuase `TimeSpan` technically represents a length of a time interval, not a time of day itself.

You can however use `DateTime.Parse` method to parse this value and then retrieve the time part using the `TimeOfDay` property as a `TimeSpan`:

```
details.UTCEventDate.Add( DateTime.Parse( details.UTCEventTime ).TimeOfDay );
```

If you wanted to specify the format even more precisely using `ParseExact`, you could use the `h:mmtt` format string where `tt` represents `AM` and `PM` part.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSpan.Parse` does not like "AM/PM" in the string.

What you can do is

```
details.UTCEventDate.Add(DateTime.Parse(details.UTCEventTime).TimeOfDay)
```